# What are the consequences of letting my advisor be the first author on my work when I have done it all?

Tags: phd, authorship, interpersonal-issues

My advisor suggested to implement an approach X on problem Y and he suspected that this is a fruitful approach. (This approach is not original but was done in the literature and no one uses it now in contrast to others approaches because there are others that are more efficient and superior (provable)). Convincing him of this even when given evidence was not fruitful at all.

It gave me the impression that he knows that I am correct but doesn't want to appear that he doesn't know in front of the department because in this department it is the norm that advisors define the problems for grad students and grad students do the work. This is because advisors want always to be the first author as it gives them career benefits, prestige and should not take a big time from the students who come on scholarships.

I took an independent approach and stopped visiting because I would gain nothing but "I am not convinced of your ideas" "I am not interested", and implicitly telling me "Do anything and I will graduate you". He did the same to all the other grad students who he gave problems in my particular field which he is not expert in but new to.

I didn't want to do trash and graduate so I spent years going on tangents on my own, going to conferences, poster sessions in well-known conferences, losing hope and crying, and trying to find another problem in the field to write my thesis in, and finally in my last year in the program (7th year now). I managed to implement a modification to circumvent the disadvantages of the neglected approach that could revive it back. And I am writing the thesis and soon the paper. Now after the work is done, he blames me for taking an independent approach and wants to be a first author for the upcoming paper and says that "it is a joint work".

What are the consequences of letting my advisor be the first author on my work vs I refuse and continue on my own?

Comment: It honestly sounds like you have not been prioritizing your academic/professional development, but rather have been sabotaging it. Get it published and graduate so you can start your career, and stop with the pointless fights with your advisor, they will only set you back.

Comment: The title of the post has very little to do with the body. Try to focus on one specific, answerable question that is of general usefulness to others that might be in a similar situation.

Comment: Your assertion that the first author gets career benefits is incorrect. The first author is the person that did most of the work and presumably wrote the manuscript. The last author is the person who supervised the project (normally the PI). There is no real benefit for an advisor to take the first authorship.